# Correct phpDoc to tell IDE of dynamic class return type

Tags: php, phpdoc

Consider this code:

```
class ParentClass {

    /** @return ParentClass  */
    public function getNew(){
        return call_user_func(array($this,'generator'));
    }

    protected function generator(){
        return new static(); // will actually return whatever class calls this code
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {}

$child = new ChildClass();
var_dump($child->getnew()); // object(ChildClass)
```

Because `ParentClass::generator()` returns a `static()`, when the child instance calls `getNew()`, a `ChildClass()` is returned. The IDE (PhpStorm in my case) has no way to resolve this since the generator is dynamically called with `call_user_func()`. As a result, the IDE thinks that a `ParentClass` instance will be returned:

[image]

Is there a way to improve the parent's phpDoc block to better reflect the return type?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out, using this phpDoc block for `ParentClass::getNew()`:

```
/** @return static */
public function getNew(){/*...*/}
```

> #### [phpDoc Types keywords](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/types.html#keywords)
>
> **self** -  An object of the class where this type was used, if inherited it will still represent the class where it was originally defined.
>
> **static** - An object of the class where this value was consumed, if inherited it will represent the child class. (see late static binding in the PHP manual).
>
> **$this** - This exact object instance, usually used to denote a fluent interface.

PhpStorm 2017.2 understands it, and recognizes that `$child->getNew()` will return a child instance. The IDE doesn't quite call it `ChildClass`, but rather `static`. Still it autocompletes the methods and properties that belong exclusively to the child class.

Comment: @Erik It may work (give the IDE correct typing info), but I think it is technically inaccurate here because I'm returning a new instance, not the existing `$this` reference.

Comment: Correct. Didnt look too close at your code before commenting :)